# Display same random key several times in a post

Tags: php, arrays, random

This code is probably not the best for click to call but it works.

I have 3 numbers that I want to random in a post. When it comes to display only once whith a unique piece of code it's OK. But when it comes to display the same random number twice lower in a post it's complicated. The displayed numbers are different.

How can I display the same random number (while refreshing the page) several times having control on this.

```
$numbers = array("800-433-7300", "800-633-3711", "800-756-8613");
switch ($numbers[array_rand($numbers)]) {
   case "800-433-7300":
      echo '<a href="tel:8004337300">800-433-7300</a>';
      break;
   case "800-633-3711":
      echo '<a href="tel:8006333711">800-633-3711</a>';
      break;
   default:
      echo '<a href="tel:8007568613">800-756-8613</a>';
      break;
}
```

I expect 800-433-7300 will be displayed in different part of the page. Next refreshing page, 800-633-3711 will be displayed as well several times and so on...

Any ideas ? Could you only suggest me a specific function, strcuture or page ressource to solve this by myself ?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure to understand, but can't you use a var to get this rand number and then use the var in your page ?

Comment: Stick the value in a variable, then use that variable as many time as you like after that point

Comment: `$save_it = '<a href="tel:8004337300">800-433-7300</a>';`

Comment: I think he means to write different numbers across multiple page reloads. I'd store it in a cookie and then, on next reload, depending on the cookie value, show another one

Comment: You could use a formatter to format it on the frontend (javascript) and just save the number as unformatet string. This woud increase readability and reduce redundancy - you could get rid off that logic and switch statement on the backend.

Comment: Thanks for your answers ! Storing the var the var was good solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a var to stock the value :

```
$numbers = array("800-433-7300", "800-633-3711", "800-756-8613");
$rand_num = $numbers[array_rand($numbers)];
```

Then use it where you need it in your page :

```
echo '<a href="tel:'.str_replace('-', '', $rand_num).'">$rand_num</a>';
```

Now if you always need the same string to echo, stock the string :

```
$numbers = array("800-433-7300", "800-633-3711", "800-756-8613");
switch ($numbers[array_rand($numbers)]) {
  case "800-433-7300":
    $rand_string = '<a href="tel:8004337300">800-433-7300</a>';
    break;
  case "800-633-3711":
    $rand_string = '<a href="tel:8006333711">800-633-3711</a>';
    break;
  default:
    $rand_string = '<a href="tel:8007568613">800-756-8613</a>';
    break;
}
```

And now you can echo the string where you want :

```
echo $rand_string;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, you want a different number to appear on each page refresh. If that is the case, I'd cycle through an array of phone numbers using cookies.

And you can use the same number for each page refreshment because it is stored in variable `$phones[$phoneIndex]`

If you need more numbers, just crank them up in the array.

```
$phones = ['800-433-7300','800-633-3711','800-756-8613'];

$phoneIndex= isset($_COOKIE['phoneIndex']) ? $_COOKIE('phoneIndex') : 0;

echo "<a href=\"$phones[$phoneIndex]\">$phones[$phoneIndex] </a>";

setcookie('phoneIndex', ($phoneIndex+1)%3);
```

Comment: Thanks @amarnasan, that is a great option too !